# Операции сложения/вычитания с ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Допустим есть класс, в котором содержится объект с типом Float, и он записывается в combobox1 и combobox2, есть TextBox1, который должен показать разницу между comboBox1 и comboBox2, чтобы это сделать, нужно вычислить какой из этих comboBox > и затем уже выполнить операцию (-). Данные, кстати, берутся из CSV файла, то есть, нужно, чтобы была проверка на цикличность, если пользователь выбрал 1, а потом выбрал другое. Спасибо заранее всем, кто откликнулся!

```csharp
 List<CPU> cpus = CPUs.GetCPUValues(); // Polu4enie spiska CPU;
            foreach (CPU cpu in cpus) // dlya kajdogo CPU v liste CPU poly4it' spisok;
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add($"| {cpu.Brand} | {cpu.Model} | {cpu.Benchmark}%"); // ComboBox1 = CPU;
                comboBox2.Items.Add($"| {cpu.Brand} | {cpu.Model} | {cpu.Benchmark}%"); // ComboBox2 = CPU;
            } 

// Sozdanie classa dlya vsex CPU;
        public static class CPUs
        {
            public static List<CPU> GetCPUValues()
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "CPU_UserBenchmarks.csv");
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    var records = new List<CPU>();
                    csv.Read();
                    csv.ReadHeader();
                    while (csv.Read())
                    {
                        var record = new CPU
                        {
                            Type = csv.GetField<string>("Type"),
                            Brand = csv.GetField<string>("Brand"),
                            Model = csv.GetField<string>("Model"),
                            Benchmark = csv.GetField<float>("Benchmark")
                        };
                        records.Add(record);
                    }
                    return records;
                }
            }
        }

        // Sozdanie classa dlya parsinga Type/Brand/Model/Benchmark'a CPU;
        public class CPU
        {
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public string Brand { get; set; }
            public string Model { get; set; }
            public float Benchmark { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код немного можно улучшить.

1) Добавление элемента в комбобоксы можно сделать так

```csharp
comboBox1.Items.Add(cpu);
comboBox2.Items.Add(cpu);
```

и переопределить `ToString()` у класса `CPU`

```csharp
public class CPU
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public float Benchmark { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => $"| {Brand} | {Model} | {Benchmark}%";
}
```

`ComboBox` сам вызовет `ToString()` для отображения.

2) Создайте обработчик события `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged` и назначьте на этот обработчик события `SelectedIndexChanged` у обоих `ComboBox`.

```csharp
private void ComboBoxCPU_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CPU leftCPU = comboBox1.SelectedItem as CPU;
    CPU rightCPU = comboBox2.SelectedItem as CPU;
    float result = (float)Math.Abs((leftCPU?.Benchmark ?? 0.0f) - (rightCPU?.Benchmark ?? 0.0f));
    textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `public override ToString() => $"| {Brand} | {Model} | {Benchmark}%";` после этой строки пишет ошибки: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1520 Method must have a return type; Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0508 'Form1.CPU.ToString()': return type must be 'string' to match overridden member 'object.ToString()';

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0201 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement;

Comment: @0day. конечно ) ошибся, поправил ответ.

Comment: Не знаете, как пофиксить эту ошибку? Я просто вставляю пункт 2 и выдает это, скорее всего, я делаю что-то не так. Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'SelectionChangedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @0day. вот что значит не тестировал, я перепутал событие с WPF, поправил ответ еще раз.

Comment: Я, похоже, опять что-то не так делаю. Я не понимаю, как оно должно сработать? После выбора в 1-ом ComboBox, а также во 2-ом, оно просто выведет разницу в TextBox1? Если да, то, видимо, я что-то опять сделал не так. Оно не показывает ошибок, но при этом не выводит. (Я никуда не добавлял обработчик, кроме кода (в самый низ кода)).

Comment: @0day. откройте дизайнер формы, выделите ComboBox, справа выберите событиыя (кнопочка с молнией "Высокое напряжение"), там найдите `SelectedIndexChanged` и назначьте ему обработчик, который вы добавили. Повторите процедуру для второго комбобокса.

Comment: Я так и делал, оказалось, что ComboBox было написано с большой (у меня просто старая версия VS). Теперь работает, но не корректно. Оно выводит значение так: если я выбрал 2-ой комбокс (первым) = значит выводит в TextBox benchmark (2го комбокса); если после этого я выбрал 1-ый комбобокс (вторым) = то выводит его значение; если я выбрал 1-ый комбобокс (при запуске, первым) = то выводит только его значение, на второй вообще не реагирует. (Извините, за мою тупость...)

Comment: @0day. используйте [отладку](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019), я не могу понять с ваших слов, в чем проблема и не вижу кода. Вам нужно понять, как ваш код работает, без этого понимания вы не сможете его дорабатывать. Ставьте точку останова в обработчик, и смотрите, что присваивается и куда.

Comment: Я попробовал. Оно Все считывает, но при этом не выполняет действие вычитания, как-будто не может определить какое из них больше.

Comment: @0day. `Math.Abs` отрезает знак у отрицательного числа как, икс по модулю `|x|`. Оно сначала просто вычитает, а потом, если отрицательное, делает положительным. При этом все равно, какое из них больше.

Comment: Я так и понял, но оно почему-то не выполняет действие. Вот код, если я Вас верно понял: `private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CPU leftCPU = comboBox1.SelectedItem as CPU;
            CPU rightCPU = comboBox2.SelectedItem as CPU;
            float result = (float)Math.Abs(leftCPU?.Benchmark ?? 0.0f - rightCPU?.Benchmark ?? 0.0f);
            textBox6.Text = result.ToString();
        }` для второго также.

Comment: @0day. обработчик должен быть один, и оба события комбобоксов должны быть привязаны к одному и тому же обработчику. Я не даром его назвал `ComboBoxCPU_SelectedIndexChanged`. Зачем вы дублируете код, если можно использовать один и тот же, когда он одинаковый?

Comment: обработчик сделал 1-им. Назначил на оба комбобокса. Значение все-равно выводит только левого ComboBox'a. А код дублирую из-за своей глупости и не знания.

Comment: @0day. показывайте весь код, отредактируйте вопрос. Только не удаляйте оттуда ничего, а допишите в конец.

Comment: Отредактировал.

Comment: @0day. Я не вижу ошибок у вас в коде. Ну кроме того что вы используете вложенные классы. Классы нужно в неймспейс перенести, чтобы они были вне класса `Form`. Но это не должно влиять на работу программы. Ставьте точку останова в обработчик. Потом все статические классы можно объединить в один и назвать его например `Hardware`, и все функции чтения данных расположить в общем классе. Как исправить проблему, которая вас сейчас волнует - не знаю. Возможно вы в дизайнере что-то не так сделали, провеяйте, вызывается ли обработчик при смене значения каждого комбобокса.

Comment: Вызывается. Но действия не выполняются, к сожалению...

Comment: @0day. Что содержат `leftCPU` и `rightCPU` когда вызвалось? Выполняйте код пошагово.

Comment: https://imgur.com/JRvnLAV

Comment: @0day. на скриншоте вы показываете объект самого комбобокса, это ни о чем не говорит. Вы выполните еще на строчку ниже и посмотрите, что у вас в `leftCPU` и `rightCPU`

Comment: В этом случае - ничего. Если я правильно отладку выполняю. https://imgur.com/8w9dydC

Comment: @0day. "ничего" быть не может, там либо `null`, либо что-то еще.

Comment: @0day. исправил формулу в обработчике, скобочки забыл. У вас в профиле `Debug` (в свойствах решения) стоит галочка `optimize code`, она не позволяет вам выполнить отладку нормально. Снимите ее. Потом `Build - Batch build`, поставьте обе галки и нажмите `Clean`, это почистит сборочные временные файлы. После чего запустите отладку, будет работать построчно.

Comment: https://imgur.com/cLIjOsT где тут optimize code? Может я не туда жму?

Comment: @0day. Options.

Comment: https://imgur.com/U2IEEGr это поставить на False? Других параметров не видно. VS 15. Я так понял это авто-оптимизация кода для Form(designer), для дебага не видно.

Comment: @0day. Во-первых, [optimize code](https://imgur.com/CD3xAbk). Во-вторых, поставьте свежую студию [VS 2019 Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/) и не забывайте ее обновлять, когда она будет просить. :)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Еще вопрос, если не сложно. Как сделать Round? (округление), чтобы не было такой лебеды. https://imgur.com/keNSFWW

Comment: @0day. [вот так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113595/c-sharp-6-how-to-format-double-using-interpolated-string)

Comment: Спасибо большое за столько уделенного времени. И столько много помощи. За это время с Вами сделал больше, чем сам за многое))) И все же, еще раз спрошу, хоть уже и спрашивал... Где мне лучше учить C#? ExtremeCode посмотрел, вроде как все понятно, но мало материала (как по мне) или это все с опытом приходит?

Comment: @0day. я нигде не учил, на примерах и гугле, читал документацию, поэтому вряд-ли смогу что-то еще подсказать. Учите ООП в первую очередь, до уровня "разбудили ночью - сразу объяснил, что такое инкапсуляция, наследование и полиморфизм" язык - это инструмент, без знаний ООП язык поможет только играться с консолью, и может что-то еще простое написать. Знание ООП позволит понять, как это работает.

Comment: Все. Понял, спасибо еще раз. На сегодня уже хватит)) А-то уже у самого мозг перенапрягся. Хах) Столько проблем из-за скобочек хахаха